# reload a variable string inside another string

Tags: string, bash, eval

I have to declare a string composed of different variables at the starting of a loop in order to print it later just with `eval $command >> file.txt` avoiding retype every time the string `$command` itself. But my `$command` string is composed of other variables and I need to be able to update them before printing. Here a brief example:

```sh
a=0
command="echo \"$a\""
for i in {1..2}; do
    ### change variable $a
    a="$i"
    ### print command with the new $a
    eval "$command"
done

### (it fails) result:
0
0
```

I need `$a` to be reloaded everytime in order to be substituted inside the `$command` string, thus the loop above will return

```sh
### wanted result
1
2
```

I know there are other strategies to achieve this, but I wonder if there is a specific way to reload a variable inside a string

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a variable inside `"` its expanded. Use a single quote for command variable assignment.

```
$a=0
$command="echo \"$a\""
$echo $command 
echo "0"
$command='echo \"$a\"'
$echo $command 
echo \"$a\"
$
```

Try

```
a=0
command='echo $a'
for i in {1..2}; do
    ### change variable $a
    a="$i"
    ### print command with the new $a
    eval "$command"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `function` instead of a variable assignment

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a=0 
command(){ echo "$1" ; }

for i in {1..2}; do
  a="$i" 
  command "$a"
done
```

---

Edit: as per `@glenn jackman` one can use a global variable

```
command(){ echo "$a"; }
```

And just call the function without the argument `$a`

```
command
```

Comment: Or use `$a` as a global variable: `cmd(){ echo "$a"; } ... a=$i; cmd`